# Empty Delta lemma prove in Isabelle

Tags: isabelle

I have defined an inductive predicate as below. And here i want to prove an obvious lemma which called emptyDelta1. But it seems that there exists some questions here.

```
type_synonym ('q,'a) LTS = "('q * 'a set * 'q) set"

inductive LTS_is_reachable :: "('q, 'a) LTS ⇒  ('q * 'q) set ⇒ 'q ⇒ 'a list ⇒ 'q ⇒ bool" where
   LTS_Empty[intro!]:"LTS_is_reachable Δ Δ' q [] q"|
   LTS_Step1:"(q, q'') ∈ Δ' ∧ LTS_is_reachable Δ Δ' q'' l q' ⟹ LTS_is_reachable Δ Δ' q l q'" |
   LTS_Step2[intro!]:"a  ∈ σ ∧ (q, σ, q'') ∈ Δ ∧ LTS_is_reachable Δ Δ' q'' w q' ⟹ LTS_is_reachable Δ Δ' q (a # w) q'"
```

The lemma is

```
lemma "LTS_is_reachable {} Δ' p x q ⟹ x = []"
proof(induction rule:LTS_is_reachable.cases)
case (LTS_Empty Δ Δ' q)
then show ?case by auto
next
  case (LTS_Step1 q q'' Δ' Δ l q')
then show ?case apply simp sorry
next
case (LTS_Step2 a σ q q'' Δ Δ' w q')
then show ?case by auto
qed
```

Idea: beacause the element in list which comes from the Delta1, so that when the delta1 is empty, that the result of list must be empty.

Any helps will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, there are a couple of improvements that should be made to your definition of `LTS_is_reachable`:

1. Note that the parameters `Δ` and `Δ'` are fixed parameters (i.e., they do not change). Thus, you should hint Isabelle by using the `for` clause of the `inductive` definition. This way, Isabelle is able to generate a simpler induction rule.
2. You should try to avoid `∧` for compound assumptions and instead use `⟹` or, even better, the Isar constructs `if` and `and`. This way, you allow for simpler proofs and better automation.

That is, your improved definition of `LTS_is_reachable` is the following:

```
inductive LTS_is_reachable :: "('q, 'a) LTS ⇒  ('q * 'q) set ⇒ 'q ⇒ 'a list ⇒ 'q ⇒ bool" for Δ and Δ' where
  LTS_Empty[intro!]: "LTS_is_reachable Δ Δ' q [] q" |
  LTS_Step1: "LTS_is_reachable Δ Δ' q l q'" if "(q, q'') ∈ Δ'" and "LTS_is_reachable Δ Δ' q'' l q'" |
  LTS_Step2[intro!]: "LTS_is_reachable Δ Δ' q (a # w) q'" if "a ∈ σ" and "(q, σ, q'') ∈ Δ" and "LTS_is_reachable Δ Δ' q'' w q'"
```

Regarding the proof of your lemma, you should use `LTS_is_reachable.induct` instead of `LTS_is_reachable.cases` as the rule for a proof by computation induction. This way, you can easily prove your lemma as follows:

```
lemma "LTS_is_reachable {} Δ' p x q ⟹ x = []"
proof (induction rule: LTS_is_reachable.induct)
  case (LTS_Empty q)
  then show ?case by simp
next
  case (LTS_Step1 q q'' l q')
  then show ?case by simp
next
  case (LTS_Step2 a σ q q'' w q')
  then show ?case by simp 
qed
```

Or, much shorter, as follows:

```
lemma "LTS_is_reachable {} Δ' p x q ⟹ x = []"
  by (induction rule: LTS_is_reachable.induct) simp_all
```

Hope this helps.